# Can't use login.live.com or Visual Studio Online on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, visual-studio

I have admin access to Windows Server 2012 R2. I need to set up Visual Studio there with TFS support to debug a server application there.

To connect with my free TFS account I need MS Live login. And this doesn't work. I can't log into https://login.live.com, all I get is a blank page with green padlock and microsoft logo in address bar. It happens both on IE11 and Firefox.

No error message.

Online version of Visual Studio setup doesn't work, offline (ISO) version works, but it can't log on my Microsoft account, so TFS is unavailable.

I tried to completely disable Windows Firewall, all Internet Explorer security - it's not it. I asked my network admin if any packets sent from the server are blocked, he double checked it and said no.

I know Visual Studio uses IE to log on to Microsoft Account and probably for some other things (like online installation and upgrades). If login.live.com doesn't work, Visual Studio won't.

What am I missing? It seems like something is wrong or missing on the virtual machine on which I'm trying it. I have and older Windows Server 2012 R2 machine and use Visual Studio Online there without problems. All I had to do there was turn the enhanced security mode off for IE and / or add all URLs for scripts used by Microsoft sites to Trusted zone. I've done all this on the other server, but it didn't help. And I think it's probably not IE, because I'm unable to see login.live.com site on Firefox too.

Comment: Have you considered using remote debugging instead of loading up the server with all that stuff? DId you install desktop experience on the server?

Comment: The application which I have to debug must be run 24/7 (it's production) and it crashes once in a couple of hours. How would remote debugging helped in this case? I can debug it on my local machine, but it happened the application ran for 48h on my VS without errors, but crashed on the server after 2 hours leaving me without a clue why. If I could connect with remote debugging AFTER it crashed, it would do the trick.

Comment: Yes, it would - remote debugging is meant exactly for not installing visual studio on a server. It is like real debugging.... remote. And, nicely speaking - this smells like a resource leak that are quite easy to find.... with a profiler. Did you install desktop experience?

Comment: No, desktop experience is not installed. I have a hunch remote debugging would be the right answer! But the bugs, they will be way nastier than that. I expect rather some failed SQL, network transport errors and race conditions, because the application use lots of concurrent threads.